# WAMP + CakePHP in a subfolder not working

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I just installed a fresh installation of CakePHP 3 using the following commands:

```
$ cd www
$ composer self-update
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app TimeTracker
```

After doing so this is my folder structure:

```
www
    TimeTracker
        ...
        webroot
            ...
            index.php
            .htaccess
        index.php
        .htaccess
   ...
   otherProject
```

where `www` is my WAMP document root.

All the files seem to download correctly. As it's [the default route](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/routes.php#L52), the url `http://localhost/TimeTracker/` should go to the Pages::display method - But, it doesn't, and I'm not sure why. This is what I observe:

- `http://localhost` - a list of folders of all the projects inside my www folder
- `http://localhost/TimeTracker/` - a CakePHP missing controller (TimeTrackerController) missing controller error
- `http://localhost/TimeTracker/blah` - a CakePHP generated error

I tried adding a `die()` statement in the PagesController->display() method, and this method is definitely not reached.

I've checked the following things:

- Apache rewrite_module is loaded
- allow rewrite to ALL on the directory in the httpd.conf file

If I use [the development server](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server), *this* works correctly (i.e. `http://localhost:8765/` is the home page of my application) however why does it not work correctly in a subfolder with WAMP?

Comment: Have you run ```composer install```?

Comment: what do u mean? Yes i have installed composer and downloaded the project using composer?

Comment: I just tried doing it but it made no difference

Comment: Have you followed the doc?

Comment: yes, it downloads everything fine.

Comment: What you are getting if trying to load the project directory in browser?

Comment: i just get an error page saying that "ProjectNameController" couldn't be found. My project is named TimeTracker so it says "TimetrackerController" couldn't be found. For some reason it tries to go to that controller, and i don't know why

Comment: You must added something in route and try to use ```bin/cake server``` from terminal and then open ```http://localhost:8765/``` and see what is happening.

Comment: Okay now it works - if i use the built in cake server it works. So the problem is with WAMP - does cakePHP not work with that?

Comment: It works but I cannot predict without seeing the entire code. So you can go with the above solution.

Comment: Since my answer wasn't a direct solution, I've deleted it and incorporated all the comments into the question for you. As I mentioned, debugging `getBase` may indicate where the error lies (it is probably something to do with apache config). Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!